# Right regexp for detect changes in mysql config

Tags: regex

I need to catch all redefined variables in my.cnf

In my case, they looks like

```
#basedir        = /usr/local/mysql
basedir     = /usr
```

So I need to extract all redefined parameters.
Search criteria that parameter was redefined: file has both strings which starts from `#param` and `param`.

Please advice me correct regexp.

Comment: What language or tool you are using for this?

Comment: What do you want to do with the pattern? Show the old definition? The new one? Just the name of the variable?

Comment: @revo I can use any tool. Preferable language is Perl

Comment: @Tim just name of variable

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/vroCEP/1)?

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^\h*#\K([_$a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?=\s+=\s.+\R\h*\1\s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y3F0TY/5)

For the regex to work, use the `m` multiline modifier and read the file into memory as a single string (you can do it with `-0777` options).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `#` - a `#` char
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `([_$a-zA-Z0-9]+)` - Group 1: any 1 or more ASCII letters, digits, `_` and `$`
- `(?=\s+=\s.+\R^\h*\1\s)` - that is immediately followed with:

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `=` - a `=` char
  - `\s` - whitespace
  - `.+` - 1+ chars other than line break chars
  - `\R` - a line break sequence
  - `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
  - `\1` - same value as in Group 1
  - `\s` - whitespace.